# How to transfer huge files from dslr to ipad

Tags: dslr

How to transfer huge videos from dslr to iPad quickly without wireless transfer and also without the usb?
I have a canon camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SD card to lightning adapter, unless you have a new M1 iPad Pro, in which case SD card to usb-c, or unless your camera uses something other than SD, such as cfast, in which case you’d use that.  The Apple supplied “Files” app is where you access the card reader, and move the photos to either local or iCloud storage.  No drivers or special software are necessary, only the hardware card reader.  Because the iPad has to supply power to the reader, check user reviews before you purchase.  Some are are less reliable than others. I have one that only works if the iPad is fully charged.